# Bare, very slim ROS node running on DD-WRT router?

Tags: ros, c++, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am looking for information about having a **ROS** **node** running on a **DD-WRT** enabled router.

The node would be used to send status data back to the ROS main system about certain router parameters and thus doesn't need any fancy ROS features.
Basically I am looking for something that is doing the ROS communication management (XML-RPC management and TCP/IP channel allocation) stuff for me.

I know that I could do that on my own, but I am not that deep into c++ programming (I don't want to use python due to the overhead) and any hints would save precious for time :)

Thanks for any help/hints in advance.
J.B.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29779/bare,-very-slim-ros-node-running-on-dd-wrt-router?/) by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2012-03-15**:
You may write a simple socket-based application, which will communicate with your host, and thus translate into ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the author of rosbridge, my bias goes without saying. Still, it is meant for exactly your situation. Here's a quick example of sending a simple UInt8 status message from C: [status.c](http://pastebin.com/LqSbbzLY). This simple client ignores any feedback from the server what-so-ever. My recommended approach would be for the WRT to open and close a fresh connection each status update. That way it doesn't have to handle long-standing connections. With this approach, the very first status update might be lost (because establishing a fresh topic can take longer than the publish request), but everything should work smoothly once the /wrtStatus (or whatever you use) is established.

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at [dd_wrt_acces_point](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ddwrt_access_point)? It may be able to do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1